SwiftUI: @FocusState highlight issue
I am struggling with an issue with @FocusState. I have a ForEach with multiple buttons, and selecting one of the buttons should highlight the button with the focus ring. However, when I lay it out like in this example, only the first button shows the focus ring, even as I tap on other buttons.
enum ButtonTab: Int, CaseIterable, Hashable, Identifiable {
    
    public var id: Self {
        return self
    }
    public var buttonTitle: String {
        switch self {
        case .one: return "One"
        case .two: return "Two"
        case .three: return "Three"
        case .four: return "Four"
        case .five: return "Five"
        }
    }
    case one, two, three, four, five
}

struct ButtonTagsContentView: View {
    
    @FocusState var buttonFocusState: ButtonTab?
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            HStack {
                
                ForEach(ButtonTab.allCases, id: \.self) { button in
                    Button(button.buttonTitle) {
                        print("\(button) selected")
                        buttonFocusState = button
                    }.focusable()
                    .focused($buttonFocusState, equals: button)
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}


I know I can disable the focusEffects and do an outline drawing myself, but I want to understand what's wrong with this approach and if there's an easy fix I can make.

Could not replicate your issue, all works well for me. On MacOS 15.2, using Xcode 16.2,
tested on real devices not Previews. Is this for visionOS?

Huh, it works when running the app, but not in Previews!

Note, works very well for me on Preview as well as real devices. Just tested on MacOS 15.2 using Xcode 16.2 in Preview of a new App.
